# select max element columns from group

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to select the maximum row of a group, but I'd like the query to return the other columns from that row. I know how MAX() can return the greatest integer in the group, but I don't know how to get the other columns for the max result.

In this example, I'd like to have a query that selects the maximum `userId` from each `group` but returns the userId and Name

```
Users
groupId | userId | name
----------------------
1       | 1      | mike
1       | 2      | dave
2       | 3      | bill
2       | 4      | steve
```

I'd like the output of the query to be

```
groupId | userId | name
-----------------------
1       | 2      | dave
2       | 4      | steve
```

I know I could do

```
select groupId, max(userId)
from Users
group by groupId;
```

and then do a subquery again on users. I'm just looking to see if there is a better way.

If it matters, I'm using MySQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
select * from users
join (select groupId, max(userId) as maxU from Users group by groupId) xx
on xx.groupId=users.groupId and users.userId=xx.maxU
```

Comment: is a subquery really the best way though? this is what i was hoping to avoid

Comment: Why are you looking to avoid the subquery?  Check the plan, I think you'll find this is pretty efficient SQL

Comment: You will need to join with subquery, there is no other way.

Comment: Don't think there is a way to avoid it, it's the structure of your data which is making this the only solution. But as Sparky said, it wouldn't be an inefficient query.

Comment: Just for the record, this can be done with windowing in DBs that support it, which excludes Mysql but includes pretty much everything else.